# How to make extracts and fragrances from fragrant plants like Sage

Tags: food, home, gardening, diy, personal-hygiene

I'm looking to try using more natural products/solutions in our day to day life and some things that I am considering are fragrances, soaps and essences (food). I have read that Sage plants are edible (the leaves at least).

So I was thinking this may be a first candidate to try with because I could make food essences/extracts/flavorings and I could also look to make clothes fresheners or perhaps fragrant perfumes that don't have harmful chemicals.

1. What are some sustainable techniques/methods I should follow?
2. Is making these sustainable
   A. For a family? (2 individuals)
   B. For a neighborhood? (10s to 100s of small families of 2 to 4)